# Type hint dictionary where the keys are classes

Tags: python, typing

I have a mapping variable which looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time

default_types_map = {
    datetime: 'DATETIME',
    date: 'DATE',
    time: 'TIME',
    str: 'STRING',
    bool: 'BOOLEAN',
    float: 'FLOAT',
    int: 'INTEGER'
}
```

I want to create a function which takes that variable as default value, but I don't know how to anotate the type hint of the keys:

```
from typing import Mapping

def to_schema(types_map: Mapping[???, str]=default_types_map):
    ...
```

In other words, what should I place in the `???` type hint if all they keys should be classes?

Comment: `typing.Type` ought to work.

Comment: @Samwise or just `type`

Comment: `typing.Mapping` is deprecated, too, consider replacing it with `collections.abc.Mapping`.

Comment: Beside the point, but you're using a [mutable default argument](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) here. From context though, I assume it wouldn't be mutated, but just to be safe, you might want to use [a read-only version of it, like `types_map=MappingProxyType(default_types_map)`](/q/2703599/4518341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are instances of `type`, so:

```
Mapping[type, str]
```

Answer (score 0):

For type hinting a class, you should use `from typing import Type`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type):

> `class typing.Type(Generic[CT_co])`
>
> A variable annotated with `C` may accept a value of type `C`. In contrast, a variable annotated with `Type[C]` may accept values that are classes themselves - specifically, it will accept the *class object* of `C`.

Comment: Also note in the docs: "*Deprecated since version 3.9*: [`builtins.type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type "type") now supports `[]`. See [**PEP 585**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585) and [Generic Alias Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias)."

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `typing.Type` meant to be used exclusively as a generic? Using it with `mypy --strict` results in `error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Type"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping
from datetime import datetime, date, time

Key = type[datetime] | type[date] | type[time] | type[str] | type[bool] | type[float] | type[int]

default_types_map: Mapping[Key, str] = {
    datetime: 'DATETIME',
    date: 'DATE',
    time: 'TIME',
    str: 'STRING',
    bool: 'BOOLEAN',
    float: 'FLOAT',
    int: 'INTEGER'
}

from typing import Mapping

def to_schema(types_map: Mapping[Key, str]=default_types_map):
    …
```

Comment: Note that `type[...]` requires 3.9+

Comment: Are you sure this is what OP's looking for? I mean, `default_types_map` is not a constant, so why restrict what type of keys it can take? Why rule out, say, `bytes`? I'm pretty sure OP's just looking for a type hint that the key is a class -- any class.